# Opening an attachment in a grandchild feature by clicking on a thumbail

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, photos

If you have a feature with a child feature ('observations') with its own child feature ('photos of observations) which provides an image attachment, is there some way to open the image by clicking on the thumbnail in the attribute table?

Here is a situation where it would be useful to be able to this:
[image]

where the grandchild thumbnail is a bit to the right of center at the bottom.  This kind of facility of course is automatic in QField, and the picture can be opened from windows explorer by a copy-paste from the file name, but is there a way to do it with one click?  The same, of course, for child features such as View from Location in the above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be achieved by using a QML widget to make an interactive thumbnail in the attribute table of the *photos of observations* layer.

The path used for each photo is relative to the folder where the QGIS project is saved using the `@project_home` variable - ⚠️I don't know if this works the same in QField⚠️

###### Widget creation

- Select *Drag and Drop Designer* from the drop down at the top of the *Attributes Form* Dialog
- Drag *QML Widget* into the *Form Layout* column
- Double-click to edit the widget

[image]

###### Widget configuration

[image]

###### QML code

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: patch
    width: 100; height: 100
    
    Image {
        id: thumbnail
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectCrop
        source: expression.evaluate("'file:///' || @project_home || '/' || \"path\"")
        smooth: true
        z: parent.z+1
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: mouseArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        hoverEnabled: true
        onEntered: thumbnail.opacity = 0.6
        onExited: thumbnail.opacity = 1.0
        onClicked: Qt.openUrlExternally(expression.evaluate("'file:///' || @project_home || '/' || \"path\""))
        cursorShape: Qt.PointingHandCursor
    }
}
```

The `expression.evaluate()` function is generated when an expression is created with the editor and inserted in the QML code using the [image] button. The expression concatenates `'file:///'` with the directory where the QGIS project is saved and the relative path of the photo in the attribute table:

```
'file:///' || @project_home || '/' || "path"
```

###### Result

This is the attribute table (form view) of the grandparent layer.

[image]

###### References

- The interactivity was based on a very stripped down version of [this blog post](https://www.opengis.ch/2018/11/13/visualize-postgres-json-data-in-qml-widgets/)
- [Scaling an image in QML while cropping to a rectangle's size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35583224/scaling-an-image-in-qml-while-cropping-to-a-rectangles-size) (adding and scaling an image)
- [MouseArea QML Type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html#cursorShape-prop) (changing the cursor shape)
- [QML: MouseArea pressed and hover](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72081615/4227297) (hover behaviour)

Comment: Thanks! I haven't managed to get it to actually work yet (no preview gets displayed), but that is probably some minor error which I will be able to learn something by tracking down.

Comment: I have to admit it took some time to get it working. A couple of things I ran into which may help: the path must contain only forward slashes, backslashes would not work for me  (even when escaped `\\ `). Any syntax mistakes in the QML code will result in a silent failure (no image, but also no error message). I didn't try with .jpg so I can't comment on whether that is the issue. Maybe try with an absolute path to see if that works, before constructing the relative path, and make sure the relative path points to the right place - sorry for being obvious, but worth checking :)